# PAW app: Filtering JSON in the response panel

Tags: json, paw-app

I recently discovered a nice little feature in the PAW app, that allows me to filter json in the response panel.

Unfortunately, it seems only to be able to select base on the key names. Is there some documentation somewhere that would explain the syntax of this filter (if any).

I was hoping actually, that it would be backed by something as powerful as [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)'s [query language](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the KeyPath in the filter you can see the example in the screenshot, it takes the format `address.geocode.latitude` for example (keys separated with dots).[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works, but only for simple path expressions.
What if I have more complex queries I want to perform -- e.g. only show paths that have a specific value.

Something akin to the following jq filter: `.addresses[] | select(.city == "New York").streetName | unique`

Comment: It isn't supported at the moment, but we will be adding more complex queries in future releases.

Comment: I do hope you will add support for jq query language (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/). Or maybe you can do even better and add some form of pluggable query language support ...